# Calling vkEnumerateDeviceExtensionProperties "twice" - is it required?

Tags: c++, vulkan

From the [man page for vkEnumerateDeviceExtensionProperties](https://www.khronos.org/registry/vulkan/specs/1.0/man/html/vkEnumerateDeviceExtensionProperties.html),

> vkEnumerateDeviceExtensionProperties retrieves properties for
>   extensions on a physical device whose handle is given in
>   physicalDevice. To determine the extensions implemented by a layer set
>   pLayerName to point to the layer’s name and any returned extensions
>   are implemented by that layer. Setting pLayerName to NULL will return
>   the available non-layer extensions. pPropertyCount must be set to the
>   size of the VkExtensionProperties array pointed to by pProperties. The
>   pProperties should point to an array of VkExtensionProperties to be
>   filled out or null. **If null, vkEnumerateDeviceExtensionProperties will
>   update pPropertyCount with the number of extensions found.** The
>   definition of VkExtensionProperties is as follows:

(emphasis mine). It seems in the current implementation (Window SDK v1.0.13), `pPropertyCount` *is* updated with the number of extensions, regardless of whether `pProperties` is null or not. However, the documentation doesn't appear to be explicit on what happens in this situation.

Here's an example, of why having such a feature is 'nicer':

```
const uint32_t MaxCount = 1024; // More than you'll ever need
uint32_t ActualCount = MaxCount;
VkLayerProperties layers[MaxCount];
VkResult result = vkEnumerateDeviceLayerProperties(physicalDevice, &ActualCount, layers);
//...
```

vs.

```
uint32_t ActualCount = 0;
VkLayerProperties* layers;
VkResult result = vkEnumerateDeviceLayerProperties(physicalDevice, &ActualCount, nullptr);
if (ActualCount > 0) 
{
    extensions = alloca(ActualCount * sizeof(VkLayerProperties));
    result = vkEnumerateDeviceLayerProperties(physicalDevice, &ActualCount, layers);
    //...
}
```

**My question is:** am I depending on unsupported functionality by doing this, or is this somehow advertised somewhere else in the documentation?

Comment: Man/ref pages are poorly maintained ATM, read the Spec directly. ; AFAIK you actually may need to call four and more times, in the improbable case if you get VK_INCOMPLETE. ; Nothing wrong with your one call aproach too and spec is plenty explicit about that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [latest spec](https://www.khronos.org/registry/vulkan/specs/1.0-wsi_extensions/xhtml/vkspec.html):

> For both vkEnumerateInstanceExtensionProperties and vkEnumerateDeviceExtensionProperties, if pProperties is NULL, then the number of extensions properties available is returned in pPropertyCount. Otherwise, pPropertyCount must point to a variable set by the user to the number of elements in the pProperties array, **and on return the variable is overwritten with the number of structures actually written to pProperties**. If pPropertyCount is less than the number of extension properties available, at most pPropertyCount structures will be written. If pPropertyCount is smaller than the number of extensions available, VK_INCOMPLETE will be returned instead of VK_SUCCESS, to indicate that not all the available properties were returned.

So your approach is correct, even though it's a bit wasteful on memory. Similar functions returning arrays also behave like this.

Also note that since 1.0.13, device layers are deprecated. All instance layers are able to intercept commands to both the instance and the devices created from it.

Comment: thanks - didn't see the new spec language. Also, my approach is not wasteful on memory - stack allocated objects don't really "count", unless you run out of stack space.

Comment: @MuertoExcobito: Stack memory very much does count. Once a virtual page of the stack is committed, you can't deallocate it. It takes up space forever. So unless you *regularly* use tons of stack space, you are taking up memory that will never be used. Also, a lot of compilers only give you 1MB or so of stack space. 1024 layers only permits `VkLayerProperties` to be 1K in size before you overflow. And `sizeof(VkLayerProperties)` is over 500 bytes. So it's not just wasteful; it's highly likely to overflow.

Comment: Fair point, although, this code runs on all Vulkan platforms with no stack overflows. Perhaps the array size could stand to be reduced a bit though, since 1024 extensions is likely overkill.

Comment: @MuertoExcobito OpenGL currently has about 600 extensions. Do yourself a favor and just dynamically allocate it (it's not like scanning exceptions is a hot path).

Comment: alright alright, I do need to fight the urge for laziness... but it's a hard battle. Still, I feel like, if the Vulkan spec was changed to verify that the property would be returned, obviously they had a use-case like mine in mind. Might have been nicer to just return extensions by an index, ala OpenGL.

Comment: @MuertoExcobito if result ever returns `VK_INCOMPLETE` then you'd need to do the double call+allocation anyway. "X is all anyone would need." is the worst kind of attitude that will get you cursed at some time in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Most Vulkan commands relays in double calls:

1. First call to get count number of returning structures or handles;
2. Second call to pass an properly sized array to get back requested structures/handle. In this second call, the count parameter tells the size of your array.

If , in second step,  you get VkResult::VK_INCOMPLETE result then you passed an array too short to get all objects back. Note VK_INCOMPLETE is not an error, it is a partial success *(2.6.2 Return Codes ... "All successful completion codes are non-negative values. ")*

Your Question :

> Am I depending on unsupported functionality by doing
>   this, or is this somehow advertised somewhere else in the
>   documentation?

You proposed create a big array before calling the function, to avoid a call Vulkan function twice.

> My reply: Yes, and you are doing a bad design decision by "guessing"
>   the array size.

Please, don't get me wrong. **I strongly agree with you that is annoying to call same function twice**, but you can solve it by wrapping those sort functions with a more programmer friendly behaviour.

I'll use another Vulkan function, just to illustrate it. Let say you want to avoid double call to :

```
VkResult vkEnumeratePhysicalDevices(
VkInstance                                  instance,
uint32_t*                                   pPhysicalDeviceCount,
VkPhysicalDevice*                           pPhysicalDevices);
```

A possible solution would be write the sweet wrap function:

```
VkResult getPhysicalDevices(VkInstance instance,  std::vector<VkPhysicalDevice>& container){
   uint32_t count = 0;
   VkResult res = vkEnumeratePhysicalDevices(instance, &count, NULL); // get #count
   container.resize(count); //Removes extra entries or allocates more.
   if (res < 0) // something goes wrong here
         return res;       
   res =  vkEnumeratePhysicalDevices(instance, &count, container.data()); // all entries overwritten.
   return res; // possible OK        
}
```

That is my two cents about the double call to Vulkan functions. **It is a naive implementation and may not work for all cases!** Note you must create the vector BEFORE you call the wrapping function.

Good Luck!

Comment: @Jherico - Thanks for the tip at stl::vector<> parameter !

Answer (score -1):

I agree with you. Repeating function calls is very anoying and leads to potetial mistakes. I did this template function to bypass the double call.

If you want to help me improve this code, feel free to add coments to this gist https://gist.github.com/Pacheco95/e63d24e1a16f2556e0f589da209f9ad9

```cpp
#ifndef VULKAN_DOUBLE_CALL_WRAPPER_HPP
#define VULKAN_DOUBLE_CALL_WRAPPER_HPP

#include <vulkan/vulkan.h>

#include <tuple>
#include <vector>

namespace engine {

template <typename T>
struct function_traits;

template <typename R, typename... Args>
struct function_traits<R (*)(Args...)> {
  using last_argument_type = typename std::
      tuple_element<sizeof...(Args) - 1, std::tuple<Args...>>::type;
};

template <typename F, typename... Args>
/**
 * This is a helper wrapper function to avoid the doubled calls for some
 * vulkan functions like `vkEnumerateDeviceExtensionProperties`.
 * Instead of repeating this behaviour:
 * \code
 * uint32_t extensionCount;
 * vkEnumerateDeviceExtensionProperties(
 *     device, nullptr, &extensionCount, nullptr
 * );
 * std::vector<VkExtensionProperties> availableExtensions(extensionCount);
 * vkEnumerateDeviceExtensionProperties(
 *     device, nullptr, &extensionCount, availableExtensions.data()
 * );
 * \endcode
 *
 * You can just do this:
 *
 * \code
 * // The vector type will be inferred to std::vector<VkExtensionProperties>
 * std::vector availableExtensions =
 *     vkCall(
 *         vkEnumerateDeviceExtensionProperties,
 *         physicalDevice,
 *         pLayerName);
 * \endcode
 * @tparam F
 * @tparam Args
 * @param func the vkCreate function to be called
 * @param args all arguments of vkCreate except last two
 * @return
 */
auto vkCall(F func, Args&&... args) -> std::vector<typename std::remove_pointer<
    typename function_traits<F>::last_argument_type>::type> {
  using T = typename std::remove_pointer<
      typename function_traits<F>::last_argument_type>::type;

  uint32_t count;
  func(std::forward<Args>(args)..., &count, nullptr);

  std::vector<T> container(count);
  func(std::forward<Args>(args)..., &count, container.data());

  return container;
}

}  // namespace engine


#endif  // VULKAN_DOUBLE_CALL_WRAPPER_HPP
```