# Can Vulkan Layers change at Runtime?

Tags: c++, c, graphics, runtime, vulkan

So I was wanting to make a library to make Vulkan programming easier. You can see it at [Github](https://github.com/jeffro256/ezvulkan), but don't expect anything big soon ;). I want to make a function called `getInstanceLayerProperties` which returns all the layer properties (obviously). Seeing as this could be slower, I wanted to optimize it. My idea is simple: store it as an pre-calculated array. All I need to know is: Can the Vulkan layers change during Runtime. For example, say I cached the values of `vkEnumerateInstanceLayerProperties`. Can new layer properties be removed, added, or changed so that if I call that function again, I would get different results?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The vkEnumerate*Properties return information about the state of the system as it exists at the time the call was made. That seemed pretty obvious to to us as we were writing the spec, but I can see how that may not be as obvious to someone new to Vulkan.

As the layers are defined outside Vulkan, they can change over time. Not likely, but they can. That is one of the reasons these calls can return VK_INCOMPLETE. A typical use would be to first make the call to get the count, allocate space for the result and then get the data. If the list grew between those two calls, the app would see VK_INCOMPLETE and know that something changed.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, I would note that this is a perfect way NOT to optimize code. It is not and semanticaly even can't be a hot-spot.
You can't even make use of the cached information unless you destroy your old instance/device and create a new one.

**Now to answer:**

Spec-wise there is no statements that explicitly prevent result invalidation.

UPDATE2: Therefore those **may** change anytime. Though that would be rare. Only definitive result is wheter `vkCreateInstance()` returns `VK_SUCCESS` or `VK_ERROR_LAYER_NOT_PRESENT`.

(Actually I kinda dislike, that practically all `vkGet*` and `vkEnumerate*` commands do not state the nature of invariability of their results. But then I somewhat forgot to raise that as a GitHub Issue...UPDATE2: did that now, before I forget again)

Implementation-wise code doing that should be open source. This should be part of official "The Loader" (also being part of the LunarG SDK). I may investigate later. Though it is reasonable to assume new set of layers is read every time from the registry (on Windows, that is). Admittedly, that is somewhat useless information anyway, since they may decide to change that behavior.

UPDATE: I just scanned it only quickly, but indeed it seems the layers are scanned anew on each call of the `vkEnumerateInstanceLayerProperties`:
https://github.com/KhronosGroup/Vulkan-LoaderAndValidationLayers/blob/74d013a5438f47a66a77d5375d1cdeef3f0beca7/loader/trampoline.c#L227

Comment: I think the first part of your answer is wrong. Calling `vkEnumerateInstanceLayerProperties` as well as `vkEnumerateInstanceExtensionProperties` is completely independent of any single instance and happens before instances are created. The whole point of those functions is too see whether or not you can create an instance with those certain layers/extensions!

Comment: How is it wrong? Are there in fact such statements in the specification? Never claimed anything about a "common reason"/expectations of how they *should* behave,

Comment: Or you mean the "before answer" part. Just saying, there is nothing to optimize. The enumeration is supposed to be done only once per instance/device creation... (of course **before** the creation)

Comment: Why would you want to call these once per instance creation? As I said before, these two functions are independent of any single instance which means that the layers and their subsequent extensions world remain the same across different creations (assuming that layers don't change at runtime). Therefore, ideally you would only want to call them once because once you've got the information, you don't need to queue it again. (Still assuming the layers don't change). What I'm asking is if that assumption is right. P.S. From your edit, it does look like the layer properties are queued each call.

Comment: The question is why would you want to call these more than once (and thus have a reasonable need to optimize it). ;; Your second statement is tautology("don't change, assuming they don't") - besides (in)dependence on instance is irrelevant to this. ;; To paraphraze, ideally you would do it in assembly. Doesn't mean it's reasonable. In your case, on average you save 0 CPU for the cost of some memory. And it doesn't even matter because it's not a hotspot command. ;; On Windows the layers are enumerated in registry (which points to some json files). Unless I read the code wrong, those can change.

Comment: As sad by @krOoze, **"Spec-wise there is no statements that explicitly prevent result invalidation"**. I guess you have no plans to persist this data on disk, as it may runs once or a few times per application launch. You should implement it when your  is library is mature and when this feature may sounds necessary. You have a lot of work to implement other nicer features,  as to eliminate the double calls to Vulkan, as I suggested  [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37662614/calling-vkenumeratedeviceextensionproperties-twice-is-it-required/37684826#37684826). Best Luck !

Comment: @AlexByrth Actually I have already encapsukted those calls in one nice, user friendly call! But now I was wondering if I should cache that result. (I know not to know, because of krOoze and Courtney